# JRebel caused WELD-001414 Bean name is ambiguous

Tags: jboss7.x, jrebel

We created a multi-module maven project but is currently encountering the error in the title on deploy.

Here's the setup (those with parenthesis rebel means there is a jrebel configuration in that project):

-MainProject:
--Model (rebel)
--ProjectA
---Web (rebel)
---EJB (rebel)
---Config (rebel)

The weird thing is, if I removed the rebel configuration in EJB it deploys successfully.

The error:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414 Bean name is ambiguous. Name bayadDunningInputHistoryBean resolves to beans [Managed Bean [class xxx.yyy.ClassBean] with qualifiers [@Any @Default @Named], Managed Bean [class xxx.yyy.ClassBean] with qualifiers [@Any @Default @Named]]
```

Base on the error, could it be that the same class is loaded twice?

Comment: It can be that some class (or configuration) is loaded twice. Will this happen if JRebel is switched off? If so, then something is up with the configuration, probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to downgrade from JBoss7.2 to JBoss7.1.3. Fortunately we were really not dependent on anything from 7.2 version but still I wonder what changed could be something about class loading.